# Google cloud sql authorize all IPs

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I can't add "0.0.0.0/0" as an authorized network for my cloud sql. Error message from client: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

If I authorize my IP address it works just fine but for some reason "0.0.0.0/0" doesn't work. Google's documentation suggests that it should work:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#dynamicIP

Thanks :)

Comment: I can't replicate this :( Adding 0.0.0.0/0 to my instance did allow me to access the database.

Can you contact `cloud-sql@google.com` with your instance name and I will look into it for you? Can you include a screenshot of the Access Control page? Thanks!

Comment: Trying this today I get the following message and can't Save the changes I've made: `You have added 0.0.0.0/0 as an allowed network. This prefix will allow any IPv4 client to pass the network firewall and make login attempts to your instance, including clients you did not intend to allow. Clients still need valid credentials to successfully log in to your instance.` and `Operation failed: The incoming request contained invalid data.` ... does anybody know whether GCP have maybe tightened their restrictions on adding 0.0.0.0/0 as a range? Perhaps I've not activated some extra hidden setting?

Comment: 0.0.0.0/0 worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Turns out that I was trying to authorize all IPv6 addresses. The cloud-sql team at Google added a new feature to authorize all IPv6 addresses by adding "::/0".

Comment: In your text is `::/0` an abbreviation for something? It is not an accepted value for the "New network" form in Cloud SQL when viewing in the console/browser.

Comment: Thanks @obl. I managed to connect using `0.0.0.0/0` (although the GUI kept displays errors & warnings, it actually accepted the value - confusing!)... my comment/question above is more specifically to check whether "::/0" is a typo or an officially accepted abbreviation/shortening of `0.0.0.0/0`

Answer (score 3):

"0.0.0.0/0" works for me!

Answer (score 0):

You want to authorize all IPv6 addresses in google cloud SQL. Please follow bellow step.

1. First you go to your sql instance and click on the edit button.
2. In the connection tab. Checked the public network.
3. Then click on add network. Give the name and in the IP4 address, you put 0.0.0.0/0.